# Is$\ \infty \times 0$ undefined in the extended real numbers?

Tags: infinity

And if it is, why? Is it a kind of postulate related to the fact that infinitely many points make a line?

Comment: You can just choose for defining it. $\infty\times 0:=0$ is a convenient option and is often practicized.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the context of calculus is undefined because the usual problems (lim product = product lim fails): 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}n\frac1n=1,\qquad\lim_{n\to\infty}n^2\frac1n=\infty,\qquad\lim_{n\to\infty}n\frac1{n^2}=0.$$
But in Measure Theory
$$\infty\times 0=0$$
and in Set Theory
$$\kappa\cdot 0 = 0$$
for any cardinal $\kappa$.

See the discussion in http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=6750333

Comment: It should be noted that, in the context of Measure Theory, $\infty\times 0=0$ is a (very useful) convention, whereas in the context of Set Theory, $\kappa\cdot 0 = 0$ is a theorem ($\kappa\cdot 0$ is the cardinal of the Cartesian product of a set of cardinal $\kappa$ and the empty set).